# NEED HELP. Author has abandoned to fix this jQuery plugin!

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to implemented this jQuery news ticker style plugin from http://www.makemineatriple.com/2007/10/bbcnewsticker

Like mentioned in the comments (around May) there is a bug and the author lost its will to give a bug fix.

The bug is: 
In Mac browsers (Firefox, Opera and Safari, all OSX) - links (a href) don’t ‘work’ until each list item has finished scrolling/revealing. Basically after this plugin has loaded, all the `a href` stops working.

Here is the code for the plugin (http://plugins.jquery.com/project/BBCnewsTicker):

```
/*
News ticker plugin (BBC news style)
Bryan Gullan,2007-2010
version 2.2
updated 2010-04-04
Documentation at http://www.makemineatriple.com/news-ticker-documentation/
Demo at http://www.makemineatriple.com/jquery/?newsTicker
Use and distrubute freely with this header intact.
*/

(function($) {

    var name='newsTicker';

    function runTicker(settings) {

        tickerData = $(settings.newsList).data('newsTicker');

        if(tickerData.currentItem > tickerData.newsItemCounter){
            // if we've looped to beyond the last item in the list, start over
            tickerData.currentItem = 0;
        }
        else if (tickerData.currentItem < 0) {
            // if we've looped back before the first item, move to the last one
            tickerData.currentItem = tickerData.newsItemCounter;
        }

        if(tickerData.currentPosition == 0) {
            if(tickerData.newsLinks[tickerData.currentItem].length > 0) {
                $(tickerData.newsList).empty().append('<li><a href="'+ tickerData.newsLinks[tickerData.currentItem] +'"></a></li>');
            }
            else {
                $(tickerData.newsList).empty().append('<li></li>');
            }
        }

        //only start the ticker itself if it's defined as animating: otherwise it's paused or under manual advance
        if (tickerData.animating) {

            if( tickerData.currentPosition % 2 == 0) {
                    var placeHolder = tickerData.placeHolder1;
            }
            else {
                var placeHolder = tickerData.placeHolder2;
            }

            if( tickerData.currentPosition < tickerData.newsItems[tickerData.currentItem].length) {
                // we haven't completed ticking out the current item

                var tickerText = tickerData.newsItems[tickerData.currentItem].substring(0,tickerData.currentPosition);
                if(tickerData.newsLinks[tickerData.currentItem].length > 0) {
                    $(tickerData.newsList + ' li a').text(tickerText + placeHolder);
                }
                else {
                    $(tickerData.newsList + ' li').text(tickerText + placeHolder);
                }
                tickerData.currentPosition ++;
                setTimeout(function(){runTicker(settings); settings = null;},tickerData.tickerRate);
            }

            else {
                // we're on the last letter of the current item

                if(tickerData.newsLinks[tickerData.currentItem].length > 0) {
                    $(tickerData.newsList + ' li a').text(tickerData.newsItems[tickerData.currentItem]);
                }
                else {
                    $(tickerData.newsList + ' li').text(tickerData.newsItems[tickerData.currentItem]);
                }

                setTimeout(function(){
                    if (tickerData.animating) {
                        tickerData.currentPosition = 0;
                        tickerData.currentItem ++;
                        runTicker(settings); settings = null;
                    }
                },tickerData.loopDelay);

            }
        }

        else {// settings.animating == false 

            // display the full text of the current item
            var tickerText = tickerData.newsItems[tickerData.currentItem];

            if(tickerData.newsLinks[tickerData.currentItem].length > 0) {
                $(tickerData.newsList + ' li a').text(tickerText);
            }
            else {
                $(tickerData.newsList + ' li').text(tickerText);
            }

        }

    }


    // Core plugin setup and config
    jQuery.fn[name] = function(options) {

        // Add or overwrite options onto defaults
        var settings = jQuery.extend({}, jQuery.fn.newsTicker.defaults, options);

        var newsItems = new Array();
        var newsLinks = new Array();
        var newsItemCounter = 0;

        // Hide the static list items
        $(settings.newsList + ' li').hide();

        // Store the items and links in arrays for output
        $(settings.newsList + ' li').each(function(){
            if($(this).children('a').length) {
                newsItems[newsItemCounter] = $(this).children('a').text();
                newsLinks[newsItemCounter] = $(this).children('a').attr('href');
            }
            else {
                newsItems[newsItemCounter] = $(this).text();
                newsLinks[newsItemCounter] = '';
            }
            newsItemCounter ++;
        });

        var tickerElement = $(settings.newsList); // for quick reference below

        tickerElement.data(name, {
            newsList: settings.newsList,
            tickerRate: settings.tickerRate,
            startDelay: settings.startDelay,
            loopDelay: settings.loopDelay,
            placeHolder1: settings.placeHolder1,
            placeHolder2: settings.placeHolder2,
            controls: settings.controls,
            ownControls: settings.ownControls,
            stopOnHover: settings.stopOnHover,
            newsItems: newsItems,
            newsLinks: newsLinks,
            newsItemCounter: newsItemCounter - 1, // -1 because we've incremented even after the last item (above)
            currentItem: 0,
            currentPosition: 0,
            firstRun:1
        })
        .bind({
            stop: function(event) {
                // show remainder of the current item immediately
                tickerData = tickerElement.data(name);
                if (tickerData.animating) { // only stop if not already stopped
                    tickerData.animating = false;
                }
            },
            play: function(event) {
                // show 1st item with startdelay
                tickerData = tickerElement.data(name);
                if (!tickerData.animating) { // if already animating, don't start animating again
                    tickerData.animating = true;
                    setTimeout(function(){runTicker(tickerData); tickerData = null;},tickerData.startDelay);
                }
            },
            resume: function(event) {
                // start from next item, with no delay
                tickerData = tickerElement.data(name);
                if (!tickerData.animating) { // if already animating, don't start animating again
                    tickerData.animating = true;
                    // set the character position as 0 to ensure on resume we start at the right point
                    tickerData.currentPosition = 0;
                    tickerData.currentItem ++;
                    runTicker(tickerData); // no delay when resuming.
                }
            },
            next: function(event) {
                // show whole of next item
                tickerData = tickerElement.data(name);
                // stop (which sets as non-animating), and call runticker
                $(tickerData.newsList).trigger("stop");
                // set the character position as 0 to ensure on resume we start at the right point
                tickerData.currentPosition = 0;
                tickerData.currentItem ++;
                runTicker(tickerData);
            },
            previous: function(event) {
                // show whole of previous item
                tickerData = tickerElement.data(name);
                // stop (which sets as non-animating), and call runticker
                $(tickerData.newsList).trigger("stop");
                // set the character position as 0 to ensure on resume we start at the right point
                tickerData.currentPosition = 0;
                tickerData.currentItem --;
                runTicker(tickerData);
            }
        });     
        if (settings.stopOnHover) {
            tickerElement.bind({                    
                mouseover: function(event) {
                    tickerData = tickerElement.data(name);
                    if (tickerData.animating) { // stop if not already stopped
                        $(tickerData.newsList).trigger("stop");
                        if (tickerData.controls) { // ensure that the ticker can be resumed if controls are enabled
                            $('.stop').hide();
                            $('.resume').show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        tickerData = tickerElement.data(name);

        // set up control buttons if the option is on
        if (tickerData.controls || tickerData.ownControls) {
            if (!tickerData.ownControls) {
                $('<ul class="ticker-controls"><li class="play"><a href="#play">Play</a></li><li class="resume"><a href="#resume">Resume</a></li><li class="stop"><a href="#stop">Stop</a></li><li class="previous"><a href="#previous">Previous</a></li><li class="next"><a href="#next">Next</a></li></ul>').insertAfter($(tickerData.newsList));
            }
            $('.play').hide();
            $('.resume').hide();

            $('.play').click(function(event){
                $(tickerData.newsList).trigger("play");
                $('.play').hide();
                $('.resume').hide();
                $('.stop').show();
                event.preventDefault();
            });
            $('.resume').click(function(event){
                $(tickerData.newsList).trigger("resume");
                $('.play').hide();
                $('.resume').hide();
                $('.stop').show();
                event.preventDefault();
            });
            $('.stop').click(function(event){
                $(tickerData.newsList).trigger("stop");
                $('.stop').hide();
                $('.resume').show();
                event.preventDefault();
            });
            $('.previous').click(function(event){
                $(tickerData.newsList).trigger("previous");
                $('.stop').hide();
                $('.resume').show();
                event.preventDefault();
            });
            $('.next').click(function(event){
                $(tickerData.newsList).trigger("next");
                $('.stop').hide();
                $('.resume').show();
                event.preventDefault();
            });

        };

        // tell it to play
        $(tickerData.newsList).trigger("play");
    };

    // News ticker defaults 
    jQuery.fn[name].defaults = {
        newsList: "#news",
        tickerRate: 80,
        startDelay: 100,
        loopDelay: 3000,
        placeHolder1: " |",
        placeHolder2: "_",
        controls: true,
        ownControls: false,
        stopOnHover: true
    }

})(jQuery);
```

Any solutions? I am not a programmer so if someone could point out where to patch it greatly appreciated!

***UPDATE:*** it seems only the links with ? mark becomes disabled.
Example: `http://url.com/blog/index.html?page=2`

Comment: Have you already tried other, newer plugins, such as vTicker?

Comment: I wanted a ticker that reads it from external xml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just happened to come across this post. I do still support the ticker, and there have been a few releases since last July.

The way to mitigate this issue was that there's now a "stop on hover" option, which pauses the ticker and completes (immediately) the display of an item when the user hovers over it (including of course being about to click it).

If this is still of relevance to you, if you still have issues with the latest version it'd be worth reading through the thread of comments; please do get in touch if you've still a problem (if one of the comments was yours and I missed it, then sorry!). The "official" way is to post a bug report on the jQuery plugins site, which fully tracks any reported issues, but I do try to respond to anyone who requests support via the blog.

Answer (score 0):

If there are any elements with the ID of `news` in your document, there might be a collision happening... Might this be the case? I'd search your html document for any occurrences of `id="news"` and correct them, seeing as though passing the proper parameters into the plugin might require a bit of extra research.

Comment: I don't see any collision happening with the elements.